# Why does my Azure application still point to default.aspx?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, azure

I have created a PivotViewer application with an Azure Web role, and it deploys on my local machine perfectly.  When I deploy it to azure, the standard default.aspx "My ASP.NET" application is the loaded page.  I can not seem to find a solution in all of the tutorials.  If I point the browser to http://solution.cloudapp.net/MyAzureStartPage.aspx, I can also find a perfect deployment, but I can't seem to get the proper home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining which page to load if none is explicitly specified is a function of the web server. Without configuration changes, the web server is never going to expect to look for your custom page.

Can you not simply rename your desired start page default.aspx? That would be the simplest approach.

Comment: Thank you, Steve.  Re-naming did the job with a few other changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add [defaultDocument](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument) element in your web.config under configuration/system.webServer node. Something like this will get your default page defined:

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <add value="MyAzureStartPage.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```